# Incorrect line ending: found carriage return (\r) without corresponding newline (\n)

Tags: android

I received error in my xml file. "Incorrect line ending: found carriage return (\r) without corresponding newline (\n).

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/btn_login"
     android:layout_width="100dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/et_un"
     android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
     android:text="Login"
     android:textColor="#AA0000"
     android:textSize="10pt" />
```

How to solve it. can anyone help

Comment: Open the layout file with notepad or vi or whatever, then save it again

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Using Eclipse on Windows?

1. Open layout file
2. Ctrl+Shift+F (Command+Shift+F in MacOSX)
3. Save the layout file and close it.
4. Delete any `.out` files the builder might have created.
5. Clean project.

Comment: Thanks for the add for Mac. I use Windows and Mac interchangeably, and suspect this is why I see more of the above errors than usual. Also added a reference for the rogue .out files.

Comment: In windows cleaning the project is enough

Comment: @323go can u tell what is this Ctrl+Shift+F do? after doing above steps it works.

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-F fixes formatting. I presume it fixes line-endings as well.

Answer (score 59):

It looks like stupid thing, But It worked for me

1. select all (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>)
2. cut (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> )
3. Paste it again (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>)
4. Save it (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>)

It really worked for me.

Comment: Great idea, re-pasting the text doesn't mess up the formatting in my version control tool, and also fixes the line ending problem.

Comment: Haha never thought I would be doing such things while developing.. +1 for quick fix..

Comment: Yeah. take that eclipse ;) +1 for quick fix

Answer (score 12):

It's easier than other answers:

**Ctrl + 1 -> Fix lines**

;)

Answer (score 7):

Yesterday, I got this very same error message.

My fix is by simply removing every newline after

```
/>
```

So, if you have

```
<Button
    />


<Button
    />
```

change it into

```
<Button
    />
<Button
    />
```

Might not be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to get this annoying error from time to time when you open an android activity `xml` file just press **`ctrl+shift+f`** to reformat your text and you’re good to go!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this in one of my layout XML files, I did the following from within ADT:

- right-click on the file in the Package Explorer
- Pick Open With -> Text Editor

Now the offending line gets highlighted with a big red X.

- I then deleted the line endings (combining the two lines) and then hit "return" to add it back in. In some cases I found that didn't quite work so I copied a similar line that didn't have the issue, and pasted it over top of the offending line (highlight the bad line, then paste). Sometimes it seemed that the real issue was with the line before or after it.

Then after saving it would show up the next bad line, so lather-rinse-repeat until it's all done.

- When all done, use right-click, Open With -> Android Common XML Editor to get back to the visual design view.

(ADT v21.0.1, on Mac OSX Lion)

Answer (score 0):

Close the xml file in the Eclipse
open it in text editor (notepad or notepad++ and so forth..)
save it.
open it back in the eclipse
In menu->Project->clean project.

Answer (score 0):

Just clean the project. In Eclipse go in project menu:

```
Project-> Clean
```

It will resolve the problem.

Comment: It is pretty clear that it won't work ... unless you ALSO do something to get rid of the incorrect line-endings.

Comment: May be what @StephenC is talking about the permanent solution! ie just delete the blank new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Cut your whole code, save the xml, paste the code again in the file and save. It also solves at times. Though not a standard way, but works.

Answer (score 0):

clean the project Project -> clean

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

First refresh the project then clean (Ctrl+shift+F).

This solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. open layout file
2. if any layout is freezed that freezed layout delete
   3.ctrl + A
   4.ctrl + shift + f
3. save

it will work