# Unknown Error in XML

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

Hi i have  made this xml file but it is throwing some error : Incorrect line ending: found carriage return (\r) without corresponding newline (\n)

Here is my XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/help_new_session" 
            android:layout_above="@+id/buttonHideNewSessionHelp" 
            />




        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonHideNewSessionHelp"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:onClick="onButtonClick"
            android:text="Hide" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you don't need a linear layout you can simply use a single relative layout

Comment: have u got the solution ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incorrect line ending: found carriage return (\r) without corresponding newline (\n)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049508/incorrect-line-ending-found-carriage-return-r-without-corresponding-newline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below process will resolve your issue.

1. Open layout file
2. Ctrl+Shift+F
3. Save the layout file and close it.
4. Delete any .out files the builder might have created(you can see .out files below the original layout file).
5. Clean project.

Comment: I think i found the fix of the problem , there was no error in my xml file . It was some eclipse reading error . Any time you get such an error just press the Combination Ctrl + 1 , and it gives you the option to fix this error automatically , it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout Now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/help_new_session" 
            android:layout_above="@+id/buttonHideNewSessionHelp"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonHideNewSessionHelp"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:onClick="onButtonClick"
            android:text="Hide" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It is looking perfect